# Should links be forbidden in spoiler text?

Tags: bug, spoilers

I noticed that spoiler text, that is, text that appears upon a click, can easily hide URLs. By clicking to reveal text, you are redirected:

`>! http://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/0/football/`

> http://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/0/football/

This doesn't seem wise. Is it a bug? Should it be fixed? I'm experiencing this issue on a touch screen device. One press to reveal the text also inadvertently presses the link.

Comment: You will hover before clicking, always. Kinda have to, y'know. Meaning - you will see what's there *before* clicking. Not sure what you are trying to fix here.

Comment: No, one press to reveal the text and I also inadvertently press on the link I didn't know was there.

Comment: @Oded Heh, jinx.

Comment: If you're on a touch screen device, you should be using the mobile version of the site which implements spoilers slightly different to avoid this situation. Mobile devices don't have a normal "hover" function so there's no way to activate a spoiler on the full version of the site without "clicking" on it, which will inherently activate anything under it which you might click too.

Comment: My browser loads the desktop version. Silly question: what's the URL for the mobile version of this page?

Comment: Click `mobile` in the footer on every page.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, it doesn't happen with the mobile version. Only the subset of people who use touch screen and the full site will experience this.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem to fix in my opinion.

Hovering over the spoiler won't trigger the URL. On mobile, clicking the spoiler to unhide it doesn't navigate either. The iOS app doesn't navigate either.

In that situation, it is just an URL. Nothing special to it. If you click the URL, that is on you.

Comment: On mobile it does. That's what I'm experiencing.

Comment: Not here. That might be a problem specific to your browser / device. Can you share some specifics? Are you viewing the desktop site on mobile? That could be a reason.